# How do you clear a custom destination?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Is it possible to clear a custom destination, and if it is, how do you do it? I can't seem to find anything about it in the settings.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Click an empty spot on the map, and you'll have the options: Move It, Leave It, Remove It.

Answer (score 6):

I just figured it out by accident. It's so simple that I didn't think to try it. You just click somewhere else on the map and it will ask you if you want to keep your marker or remove it.